# Changing background color of each cell in Data Grid

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, datagridview

After I figured out how to change the different cell's border colors using the RGB values to generate a random color, I now want to change the background color of each cell as well. This is for `DataGridView`. Below is my relevant code that allowed me to change cell border colors and now somewhere in that code lies a way to change background color of each cell but I am not familiar with this code since it is from a freeware. Does anyone know what I must change in this code to affect the background color of each cell?

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/WNBReUys

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use the DefaultCellStyle or set style during FormattingApplied? You should not need to do custom painting for this.

Comment: @DavidHall The reason is that this is a fragment of a freeware that allows me to print DataGrids in a specific format and thats how that part of the freeware was written...I simply pass my Datagrid control to it and it handles the printing for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution printing a background color is similar to the pen solution except you need to use a brush, usually a `SolidBrush`:

```
Dim brushColor as New SolidBrush(someColor)

e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushColor ,_
                         New Rectangle(ColumnLeft(ColPage, ColAt), _
                                       tmpTop, _
                                       ColumnWidth(ColPage, ColAt), _
                                       CellHeight))
```

Note that since you are drawing text and other graphics on this rectangle, you probably want to paint the background color first, before all the other graphics. (Otherwise, you will end up with only a solid colored rectangle with no text.)

Comment: Thank you sooo much <3 you! It worked! Since I am not familiar with VB.Net or DataGrids I dont quite understand difference between pen and brushes.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to change DataGrid BackColor.
Usually, you assign an array, table or dataset as DataSource of your DataGrid. So, I looped in my DataTable which is my data source, then look for the index of the line I want to change.

```
 Private Sub DataGridForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dgr1.DataSource = TimeDifftbl
    dgr1.PreferredColumnWidth = 250
    Dim cellText As String
    Dim dr As DataRow
    For n As Integer = 0 To TimeDifftbl.Rows.Count - 1
        dr = TimeDifftbl.Rows(n)
        cellText = dr.Item(2)
        If cellText = "Tot. RunTime" Then
            dgr1.CurrentRowIndex = n
            dgr1.Select(n)
            dgr1.SelectionBackColor = BackColor.LightGray
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```